# Swagger UI not able to resolve $ref in definitions

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

My swagger file looks like the following:

paths:
  /ordercreate:

```
post:
  parameters:
    - name: OrderCreateRQ
      in: body
      description: The OrderCreateRQ request body
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/OrderCreateRQ'
  responses:
    200:
      description: Success response
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/OrderCreateRS'

definitions:
  OrderCreateRQ:
    $ref: './common/OrderCreateRQ.schema'

  OrderCreateRS:
    $ref: './common/OrderCreateRS.schema'
```

I do have the schemas in the "common" folder as valid JSON files.

When I am pulling it up on SwaggerUI 2.1.4, it says:

```
./common/OrderCreateRQ.schema is not defined!
./common/OrderCreateRS.schema is not defined!
```

I have tried moving the schema files in the same directory and referring, but it fails. 
What am I missing here? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a SwaggerUI issue. I took the latest version v2.2.6 and the same code works.